# Calling R script from python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, call, rpy2

I'm very new to rpy2, as well as R.

I basically have a R script, script.R, which contains functions, such as rfunc(folder). It is located in the same directory as my python script. I want to call it from Python, and then launch one of its functions. I do not need any output from this R function. I know it must be very basic, but I cannot find examples of R script-calling python codes.
What I am currently doing, in Python:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

def pyFunction(folder):
    #do python stuff 
    r=robjects.r
    r[r.source("script.R")]
    r["rfunc(folder)"]
    #do python stuff

pyFunction(folder)
```

I am getting an error on the line with source:

`r[r.source("script.R")]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 226, in __getitem__
    res = _globalenv.get(item)
TypeError: argument 1 must be string, not ListVector`

I quite do not understand how the argument I give it is not a string, and I guess the same problem will then happen on the next line, with *folder* being a python string, and not a R thingie.

So, how can I properly call my script?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`source` is a `r` function, which runs a `r` source file. Therefore in `rpy2`, we have two ways to call it, either:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r = robjects.r
r['source']('script.R')
```

or

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r = robjects.r
r.source('script.R')
```

`r[r.source("script.R")]` is a wrong way to do it.

Same idea may apply to the next line.

Comment: I want to launch the rfunc function, defined in script.R, with the argument *folder*, which is given as an argument to my python function.

Comment: For the next line, `r.rfunc(folder)` works, same way as your solution. It seems I was looking for too complicated things while the solution was extremely simple. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, exactly. `r["rfunc(folder)"]` will pass `folder` as a string `'folder'`, which is probably not what you want. I run up of up votes today, I will do that tomorrow. Cheers!